# Typescript believes `this` is abstract because the base class is abstract, requiring nasty cast

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

I have a base class which is `abstract`, extending `HTMLElement`, which calls `CustomElementRegistry.define`. Typescript doesn't like the use of `this` as the second argument because the base class is `abstract`. But this seems incorrect, because obviously the final class can never be abstract, and as far as I can tell `this` belongs to MyClass in the example. I have to use the ugly cast below. The code (in its full implementation) actually works. Is there a better way to do this?

P.S. sorry that my previous example was wrong, and thus the first three answers apply to the bad example.

```js
abstract class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  // Without a cast, the `this` argument gets this error:
  // tsbug.ts:12:6 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'.
  //   Type 'CustomElement' is not assignable to type 'CustomElementConstructor'.
  //     Type 'CustomElement' provides no match for the signature 'new (...params: any[]): HTMLElement'.
  static register(name: string) {
    customElements.define(
     name,
     this, // This argument gets the error.
     // If you replace the above `this` argument with the one below, it works.
     // this as unknown as new () => HTMLElement,
     {});
  }
}

class MyElement extends CustomElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

const e = new MyElement();
MyElement.register("my-element");
```

Comment: Please provide the error message your (linter?) IDE gives you when using "this" as an argument as well as a skelet implementation of your base class

Comment: Oh, sorry. Here is something you can compile - or fail to.

Comment: `this` is a reference to an _instance_ of a class, not a class itself. I believe `define` expects a reference to a class itself.

Comment: It does not make sense to call customElements.define from the constructor since that would register the class multiple times and you could not use it from HTML until you instantiated it yourself. That error is showing you that what you are doing is incorrect, it takes a constructor, not an instance.  customElements.define os typically called once,  immediately after it's defined.

Comment: Since your class is abstract, it should not be concerned with registering the element constructor, each concrete class will register itself.

Comment: Sigh. Please bear with me, my example is wrong and I will submit a new edit of it.

Comment: You want `CustomElement.register("")` to be a compiler error, right? But it isn't.  So the warning you're getting is correct, nothing guarantees that `this` will be a non-abstract constructor. If you want to guarantee that you should use a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEje2N). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable dupe target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, @jcalz, that's what I needed. I've never before seen typing of `this`, that's the clue, I guess.

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is incorrect. An instance of `CustomElement` *should not* be trying to register *itself* with custom elements. That logic is on a higher-level than what belongs inside the class.

Consider what would happen if you were to write

```
const a = new MyElement();
const b = new MyElement();
```

Both of these would try to register, and re-register themselves with the custom element registry. Additionally, this would happen every time you would try to use the custom elements in your mark-up. This is not good.

Instead, your code should model a setup closer to:

```
customElements.define("custom-element", MyElement, {});
const a = new MyElement();
const b = new MyElement();
```

Design issues aside, what you are looking for is not possible to do within a proper OO paradigm.

A class does not get a static reference to itself that can accessed dynamically. TypeScript is correctly flagging an issue:

```
customElements.define(
     "custom-element",
     this, 
// This is a reference to an *instance* of a class, not to a constructor. 
/// Casting will not make it work. You need a reference to the class you want to register.
     {});
```

Comment: Eh, I didn't suggest to violate anything: the code I have shown is perfectly legitimate is some scenarios...

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio It _does_ violate OO, and there's a clear consequence to it: every instantiation will re-register a new constructor for the element. I believe it will throw an error upon any subsequent registration call (but I haven't tested it).

Comment: The consequence you mention is *intrinsic* to the architecture of the registration process (and the fact that that registration is not idempotent, and maybe even sensibly so: but) there is just nothing intrinsically wrong in extracting the constructor from an instance in order to pass it to some consumer for some reason. -- And now you admit you are not even sure that repeated calls error, which means you have not even really started answering the question at all...

Comment: @Julio that code never makes sense

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I went out of my way to run the code, and apparently it doesn't work at all (see console): https://jsfiddle.net/9ov85zr0/

Comment: That is *not* my code, I haven't tried to instantiate anything for one thing: you guys should reread the title of the question and how the thing up to my answer actually started.  That said, my answer is eventually a poor one, I admit it, but claiming mispatterns in the name of OO is totally off mark...

Comment: Sigh. Please bear with me, my example is wrong and I will submit a new edit of it.

Answer (score 1):

You say "the final class can never be abstract" but TypeScript begs to differ.  By default nothing stops you from calling a [`static` member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members) of an [`abstract` class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members), so the following is allowed:

```
CustomElement.register("xyz"); // allowed
```

And you can also subclass an `abstract` class with another `abstract` class, and again, you could call the inherited `static` method there too.

```
abstract class Foo extends CustomElement { }
Foo.register("abc"); // allowed
```

So that explains the compiler error in which `this` is only known to be assignable to `typeof CustomElement` and not some concrete subclass.

---

The approach I'd take here is to give the `register()` method a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), which lets you restrict the `this` type of the object on which the method is *called*.  Like so:

```
abstract class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
  static register(this: new () => HTMLElement, name: string) {
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    customElements.define(name, this, {}); // okay
  }
}
```

Inside of `register()` the compiler is now convinced that `this` is of a type assignable to `new () => HTMLElement`, the widest type allowed by [`customElements.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define).  Now `register()` compilers without error.

Furthermore you will get the desired compiler errors if you try to call `register()` on an object which is not a concrete constructor:

```
CustomElement.register("xyz"); // error!
// The 'this' context of type 'typeof CustomElement' is not assignable to method's 'this' 
// of type 'new () => HTMLElement'. Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a 
// non-abstract constructor type.

abstract class Foo extends CustomElement { }
Foo.register("abc"); // error, same reason
```

while still allowing the intended calls when the constructor is concrete:

```
class MyElement extends CustomElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
}    
MyElement.register("my-element"); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgV0gewFsBRZAUwNIDtFSAPCKgEwwAkAVAWQBkTyrEA3gCgESPJUhRs8PFAAUASgQCEYbAAdS8hQG4EAXxGqIwCAEtYCKKQDmZyFrkQAFvYBcCSqQDuCRQgBeAD4Edm5eCmoAGk9gCg9JM0obJWFRUVhcCEII-jAAOkZSADMk0jlKONIYl3sYgX1dI0NDIRx8YjJIiHzrOwd5ACJaAE8AL0HdBAB6aYQtKFkAQiFZhDZnUgQAclqwbbFqOkQ8YoQIEc0di81TrCycrv4D+088RDQwMxtKkDJzvAICguPCMbYYXaufYIVZzO43LbbLy+fzBUKcHhPajbfJYYCUSjvBCfb6UYlk0CSOCIWDiSTSbJQc6XLbZYkwtaEygAWkp0Gph3pMiZCPyQiEfJg8CQqHQCAAYnhAccmBh2tlOnxqMoDEJFXherZ7AwhqBYJM9GsFstxShPggOCNctqVZRmPcOs7BEZaRJoAzZP4VGpNNo9C1bXSaIFPD4HU6sRBFDohI6vYb+ia5IMCCNuaRExaZnCANbAEZAA)